# Group Permissions

Tags: permissions, groups

I have a directory named DIR and a group GRP and two users, root and jortiz.  I created DIR when logged in as root and set the group ownership of the DIR to GRP:

```
drwxrw-r-x 2 root GRP 4096 2009-11-12 01:04 DIR
```

I also added jortiz to the GRP group and logged out.  I logged back in as jortiz and tried accessing the DIR directory, however, I keep getting the following error:

```
cd: DIR: Permission denied
```

What might I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: It's a shell programming question.

Comment: The problem is that you really should be sure where to move the question before moving it!  Anyway, I don't have enough rep to vote to move a question, I'm happy with just answering it here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  It's not directly related to programming, but I am writing a shell script to set up the permissions for my users (if that counts for anything).

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the executable flag for the group.  Permissions should be `drwxrwxr-x`.  You can fix that with `chmod g+x DIR`.

Comment: 'r' for dirs means you can list its contents. 'x' for dirs means that you can view their contents' metadata: perms, owner, group, size, mtime. It's a convention here, not very logical :)